# Typescript: Dynamic assignment to a typed map

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing some abstract entity system for fun where I have entities with traits. Traits have some fields, including dynamic `data` field:

```typescript
enum TraitId {
  Movable = 'Movable', Rotatable = 'Rotatable', Scalable = 'Scalable', Collidable = 'Collidable'
}

interface TraitDataMovable {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

type TraitDataMap = {
  [TraitId.Movable]: TraitDataMovable
  , [TraitId.Rotatable]: number // angle
  , [TraitId.Scalable]: number // scale
  , [TraitId.Collidable]: boolean // collides or not
}

interface TraitData<ID extends TraitId> {
  id: ID;
  data: TraitDataMap[ID];
  disabled?: boolean;
}

type EntityTraits = {
  [TID in TraitId]: TraitData<TID>
}

class Entity {
  id: string;
  traits: Partial<EntityTraits> = {};
}
```

So far I achieved correct behavior with manual assignment:

```typescript
const ent = new Entity();

ent.traits.Rotatable = {
  id: TraitId.Rotatable, // id can only be Rotatable
  data: 100 // data can only be number
};

ent.traits.Collidable = {
  id: TraitId.Collidable, // id can only be Collidable
  data: true // data can only be boolean
}

const hasCollision = ent.traits.Collidable.data; // correctly typed as boolean
```

And now I'm trying to write function that adds any trait to the entity:

```typescript
function addTraitToEntity(entity: Entity, traitData: TraitData<TraitId>) {
  entity.traits[traitData.id] = traitData;
  // Type 'TraitData<TraitId>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
}

function addTraitToEntity2<TID extends TraitId>(entity: Entity, traitData: TraitData<TID>) {
  entity.traits[traitData.id] = traitData;
  // Type 'TraitData<TID>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<EntityTraits>[TID]'.
  // Type 'TraitData<TID>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
}
```

They work with `// @ts-ignore`, however I'd like to get rid of it and do it right. And understand how to have such system typed correctly.

[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgTgQwJYBcCSATKBvAUFKAWQHsA3BAIwBtgoBeKAchPOuEYBooAlYlBfm3pNe-QTU5QAygGMEVSjWGNZ8xey4BhYlSpIM65dt371jXAF9cuJCBTA4AMwQza8ZCgAiAhC0N4CAA8ALihwCAoHAG58KABPUPDIuBirXBQ4gAc3RFRvfkIETOEAqABtd1RMADo-NgBdUMqvHzqaWK4K3PQMatEfBsTIZKgAelGoBBAAc3aCTuaa1QVBsOGHMYmAZzk5qAXumuM9A1WKYh1gKc344C2oYjgw4ktrW3snFxyPfIQAHjQnigwEC9hAGHuiwwAD4cLF9KFATECAZ+E1ur9CpkyoD6sioBgkFt1BgAPyhc6XKapawZbJQACidlQcWa9wYpQqgKgtlghwwjT5Px8fxggOhr1wMgUW3uTJQLLhBARUC2KDgtmmyn0jHx6o8W1CAAUEHAFfI-vKWWzYRyLDSpcQQGrgXZhCBgAB3RnMjIACgAlDFcKAUNV9agtn0+AMlBz4Rh0R4av1xMAuOMeVg5CAHiAqHEoJEeDG07FUQhQgBGAAMNZuFagObzBaLtCSDkswdD4e6UeOpiE8eViaFVV6A9ONAzE30TeuTtbxcn6nLPlC6rAtEzjebi8LxcpNCmkpkTpdAAsEFsB1skE7hD2Iyh+zoTupqhWojcz3A4MAZBQVs6WALBryLC5jxAaxHDAEBAPvXMEAwDBmhgYgrX9UMWVCTC4i4Z9fiTPIRShaEAyVV0FQyXsDTKQifGqfR6mEBj+HxTMYCyWhGGaX5RX5aFGB5e4QD4SZZSQaYQEMFBiCgECmDgjBgEcWxQMYapJVg+CFQfZDUO6dC8IAJlFbkQTBCExx6aE-WwjJcN9fCFIxdcbP4sVPHIyiHLiWjI3otz+CYgVWOChAOImLj6V4iLzO84SiWeFAJLvaTZPkxTGBNM0kAtPCbS5Tx6k02JOO4pg+NI8UktE8Tr3SmShDkhTKsYZTVPUjBzDSIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following. TS somehow loses information about `TID` when trying to resolve the type of `traitData.id` expression. Consequently, the only information it has at the moment is the constraint to `... extends TraitId`. That's why TS resolves `traitData.id` expression to `TraitId` or `TraitId.Movable | TraitId.Scalable | TraitId.Rotatable | TraitId.Collidable` instead of `TID`.

---

The simplest way to achieve the goal is to use the modified variant of `addTraitToEntity2` function with existing types:

```
function addTraitToEntity2<TID extends TraitId>(entity: Entity, traitData: TraitData<TID>) {
  (entity.traits[traitData.id] as any) = traitData;
}
```

Negative aspects:

- `as any` is not a good way to solve issues;

Or as [@Linda Paiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste) suggested, but as a generic function. Because without type variable you would be able to pass specific `id` member with an incorrect `data` member and vice versa.

```
function addTraitToEntity2<TID extends TraitId>(entity: Entity, traitData: TraitData<TID>) {
    entity.traits = {
        ...entity.traits,
        [traitData.id]: traitData
    };
}
```

---

Meantime, I refactored your code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiAuBLeBPAKgJwIbLSgDsFAN4BQUUAsgPIBqAggEIAyMANOVAMoDC9zTVhwoAlamnoSW7Tj2rNmASQAigmQF9SpVIVgJk6bMkoB7AG5YARgBtgtLNbBEAvCU4APAFxRwES8AwAbk4Ub19-INJNbQIiOCRUTBx4AB5aAD4oVzIKABMseCxvWmC8xABnK1tcgH5vSxMTWywQYOjEBACAMywAYzj9RKN4crcKAG14gyTcWIA6GgZpAF1vKaHklPXDZNMLGzsHJ3TSqEnBndnCOd5%20NVW9BMvU8ICTznOnmfg8a7EJKSsB7bb4pV4Yd4TEHDX7AOZyBQqe5rC6ghpNYAtE5QKJaKzleDYXrwKC9axYcqjbYpNAiKDAdzwUC5KmomGxTI5KD4DAmJnE4C5UkmEAEjBgYkmDAACk4FB5fOAAqFiFy3jFHQA5sIKNzefymULCclyt4AApYDBIBwpLm6s6qqAdKC04Fsk3jVXLU4UdSZbKaCgAShIgZx8rANkQvSgWFyuVBaBU9MZzNGtPS0tV3iTyjYUGNyBRX2G5XGueWIbtBYAFhU5oWRp7csssgXhqdohGozGMMAIOZgInkwymSAWS6RJnsy6VFW5bX642y1622Bx8Auh1BZ2tN3rNGoJrgD9hjSR6nx%20mp1m1bPlEHi9NS%20WVK2AD5Qde5TfboXV3oRQJdtkjbeA63KBsXy9H0nS6KBpUbed7QoPt4DADAQDGFCKDmPDGx1HD8kKbwdGAEx4MbOZiKwLJnFcAAiExLAAKyVeAGKgGpsJw3D8OGaiCiwBd7XUKBSIEmiRKgMSKUeZ8PQrWCw1Qk8MKw79fxAHdOE0aIyQpUYeDAAkTAgbYUzHCdqWhZJYU5Th8EjA8Y0A0VCQleApWlBUDUFJ07w1EBNWQ3VyjAQgZVVINd30oCSV6EyvPMi4220gB3KBjNMlKnmlBjEpygBGBiYtIQrku2OY4wTYZpVsq44QRJRVGkfMuRoiSnB1XIKiqQVvB6axymADh1DKiqzKqmrvnq91GoWOg1HazhOp4qAvCgAA2QioFCKAAE4dT0iakqmi45j7AczCHOqGp%20eZFjUCb4qga7%20u%20NtJtygw5mPU9kjmks7PmZqkWkGKgA)

Improvements:

- Less number of TS types;
- `Entity` was introduced as an abstract class which includes API for add, remove, retrieve traits;
- Traits become a member of `Entity` class;
- `Entity` class is now generic and you can customize which traits entity can have;

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as valid within 2 days, if no one comes with idea how to make TS understsand that traitData.id is TID. 
Also thanks for idea to propagate that "TraitDataMap" to just Trait<ID>. 
I don't think it is worth to bloat Entity class in my example code stripped to explain the problem, not create a working system, but thanks for an efforn anyway

Comment: You're welcome. Refactored code as I think shows how it should be written in canons of OOP paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a roundabout solution to just avoid the error.  It will work if you replace the entire object `entity.traits` instead of assigning just one property, like this:

```
function addTraitToEntity(entity: Entity, traitData: TraitData<TraitId>) {
    entity.traits = {
        ...entity.traits,
        [traitData.id]: traitData
    }
}
```

I've been playing around with this and I haven't really got a satisfying answer as to why your method doesn't work, but I think part of the problem is with typescript understanding that the key `traitData.id` matches the value `traitData`.